# One arithmetic operation needed to refer to neighbours in Array

Tags: arrays, math, reference

I got an dynamically sized array like this
[2,5,3,4,6,7]

Now I want to reffer to the left and the right neighbour of an element.
For example I got the index = 3

Which would be element with the value "4". To get the right neighbour I can just make

index + 1 MOD length = 4

If I am at the right end, say index = 5, I get 5 + 1 MOD 6 = 0. So It takes the first element in the array. That is what I want. Now I also want to achieve the same with the left neighbour. How can I do this?

If I got index = 0, I have index - 1 = -1. How to get the indexnumber of the element on the right side with one arithmetic operation? So that I can calculate this operation every time on each index.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(length + index - 1) MOD length should do the trick.

So, when length = 6:

- If index = 0 left_index = (6 + 0 - 1) MOD 6 = 5
- If index = 4 left_index = (6 + 4 - 1) MOD 6 = 3 ...